# Android socket stream not cuting down when connection closed

Tags: android, sockets, stream

I have do async method which is getting sound stream from ip from specific port.
But some times it is not recognize by application if stream port is closed or not, here is code:

```
protected Integer doInBackground(String... params) {
                        // define data byte
                        byte[] data= new byte[400];
                        try {
                        // boolean for loop
                            looping = true;
                            // create new socket
                            socket = new Socket(params[0], Integer.parseInt(params[1]));
                            // getting socket time out
                            int time = socket.getSoTimeout();
                            // closing delay of tcp
                            socket.setTcpNoDelay(true);
                            // checking for looping
                            publishProgress(); 

                       // problem is here, some times looping is not recognize when socket closed
                       // here is test: 
                       // when stream started then connection closed, 
                       // socket connection doesn't recognize if connection closed or not even if looping is false
                       // loop doesnt break
                            while (looping) {
                                if (!socket.isConnected()) { // if socket not connected close
                                // if connection closed publish next progress to onProgressUpdate
                                    publishProgress();
                                    // setting looping boolean to false and breake while loop
                                    looping= false;
                                } else { // if socket connected 
                                    // confirmation integer
                                    int onay = -1;
                                    try {
                                    // setting socket time out
                                        socket.setSoTimeout(100); // setting socket time out
                                        // defining input stream for media player
                                        InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                                        onay = is.read(data); // if read data is possible set onay integer

                                        if (my.mp.isPlaying()) {  // if media player playing 
                                            my.mp.pause(); // pause it
                                        }
                                    } catch (SocketTimeoutException en) {
                                      // setting socket time out
                                        socket.setSoTimeout(time);
                                    }
                                    // write data to track
                                    if (onay != -1) {
                                    // if confirmation onay not -1 write data to track
                                        my.annocuncementAudioTrack.write(data, 0, data.length);
                                    }
                                    OutputStream out = socket.getOutputStream(); // getting stream from socket 
                                    out.write(0); // write to outputstream file
                                }
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                        // return one in case of any error
                            return 1;
                        }
                        // return zero when operation finish
                        return 0;
}
```

Problem is even looping boolean changed to false while loop is not breaking, why is that. thank you.

Comment: you have to disconnect the socket.

Comment: You are ignoring end of stream when it occurs. See my answer in the duplicate. You don't have to reset the read timeout when it occurs.

Comment: Problem is device doesn't recognize socket state when connection of device is closed completely and still waits for audio stream (socket.isClosed, or socket.isConnected same result), @EJP your dublicate answer did not worked to..